# Magento 2 : Newsletter Subscription Event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, newsletter

Is there **an event in Magento 2 for Newsletter Subscription from the Profile page**?

How do I find out when a user updates their newsletter subscription preference from this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the predispatch/postdispatch events triggerred by the controller action class. In your case:

- `controller_action_predispatch_newsletter_manage_save` to observe a behavior **BEFORE** the save method is called.
- `controller_action_postdispatch_newsletter_manage_save` to observer a behavior **AFTER** the save method is called.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that. These events I guess not available in the Magento 2.x list of events. Are you sure these work in 2.x version?

Comment: @Guruji those events are dynamic so the event name depends on the controller action class. They are dispatched here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L92

Comment: Ohh.. Never thought of the dynamic events. This is a great insight. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Guruji those are not the only dynamic events. There's a lot of events for CRUD operations too. For example, in M1, here's the list of events. Most of the dynamic ones listed here are the same for M2: https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/d8157c6b492238af2ed7809e5e3a134e

Comment: Thanks @Raphael.. I just got into Magento a week or 2 back for developing an extension! This is a great insight I was not aware of. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @Raphael I tried using the **controller_action_postdispatch_newsletter_manage_save** event but it doesn't seem to be updating the value when I check the status using the following lines 
`$checkSubscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByEmail($user['email']);
        if($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed())`
Is there a way to get the updated status subscribed/unsubscribed using the event data?

Comment: @Guruji you should be able to get the updated status by calling `$observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed');`

Comment: Awesome!! Yet again sir you have made my day! Please let me know if I can buy you a beer! :D

Comment: @Guruji hahaha anytime man, if you ever come to a Magento event and it happens that I'm here too, feel free to do so ;)

Comment: Hey all! That worked perfectly for the customer account section. However, I am struggling to find the event for the footer subscription form event. The one mentioned in the answer doesn't work for the footer form subscribers :/ Is it a different event?

Answer (score 7):

Fernando Miguel's answer doesn't work, change

```
newsletter_subscriber_save_before
```

For

```
newsletter_subscriber_save_after
```

After that, you'll be able to get the subscriber ID. Or even get the email using

`$observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber()->getSubscriberEmail()`

All these functions are available too:

```
 int getStoreId()
 $this setStoreId(int $value)
 string getChangeStatusAt()
 $this setChangeStatusAt(string $value)
 int getCustomerId()
 $this setCustomerId(int $value)
 string getSubscriberEmail()
 $this setSubscriberEmail(string $value)
 int getSubscriberStatus()
 $this setSubscriberStatus(int $value)
 string getSubscriberConfirmCode()
 $this setSubscriberConfirmCode(string $value)
 int getSubscriberId()
 Subscriber setSubscriberId(int $value)
```

Comment: On Magento 2.3.3, trigger "newsletter_subscriber_save_after" definitely works . Many thanks

Comment: yeah, three more times in one session, so that for sure) such a practice since Magento 1 only started there twice, as they say, they were verified - they started to start three times)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond `controller_action_predispatch` and `controller_action_postdispatch` if you want to work with model events just declare on your Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module_observer_myobserver" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

On [Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php) example you have `$_eventPrefix` variable. This variable will be used on [Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/89adbabc2a295c9b6f88768d541fd2858f59aae5/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L677) to generate dynamic dispatches for models at before and after events. Also on [Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php) example we have `$_eventObject` to access the class methods as the following snippet observer example:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $subscriberId = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber()->getId();
    $this->logger->notice('subscriber ID: ' . $subscriberId);
}
```

Note that `getSubscriber()` uses get + `$_eventObject = 'subscriber'` value as described on var comments.