# Event for Post Dispatch on Newsletter not working in custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I have created an event on my new custom module to display something after new newsletter subscriber have subscribe both nothing is showing. I reference  this for event [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170157/magento-2-newsletter-subscription-event) for  both postdispatch and predispatch

The event.xml shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_newsletter_manage_save">
    <observer name="controller_action_dispatch_newsletter" instance="Company\Module\Observer\Update" />
  </event>
</config>
```

This is the observer is shown below /observer/Update.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Company\Module\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Update implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    echo "email";
    exit; //un commet this to make sure event works
}
 }
```

Thank You

Comment: Event's name looks fine. Observer folder has to be with capital O, is it?

Comment: @Nikolas Observer folder is fine

Comment: Give a try placing the events.xml file under frontend/events.xml

Comment: Will try this @Nikolas

Comment: any update on the above?